# force:createRecord for Article type

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, knowledge

I have created an article type named knowledge and would like to be able to create them from an app layout using force:createRecord, however, the modal box does not render any fields, nor do I get any error message. Is this functionality supported for knowledge article types?

my component markup is as follows:

```
  <div class="slds-form-element">
      <ui:button label="Article" press="{!c.createKnowledge}"
            class="slds-button slds-button--brand" />
  </div>
```

my controller is as follows:

```
({
createKnowledge : function (component, event, helper) {
    var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "knowledge__kav"
        });
      createRecordEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

this is what is rendered:
[image]

Comment: Can you check the **FLS** on the Knowledge object?. It might be a reason too.

Comment: thanks, I figured it out, need to enable lightning knowledge (Beta) from classic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like lightning knowledge needs to be enabled for this functionality to work. Functionality was added with Spring '17 and is documented [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_lightning_knowledge_setup.htm)

> Here’s how to move to Lightning Knowledge.

Make sure that your org meets all the prerequisites.

> -You must have only one article type, be in single language mode, and have no more than 300 data categories.
>
> -From Setup, enter Knowledge in the Quick Find box and click Knowledge Settings.
>
> -Under General Settings, select Enable Lightning Knowledge.

And last but not least, an IMPORTANT note:

> After you enable Lightning Knowledge, you can’t go back to Classic Knowledge. Only enable Lightning Knowledge if you’re prepared to permanently move Knowledge to Lightning Experience.